Need a tag for Legacy iPod (pre-iOS/touch) questions
I have just asked a question about legacy iPod click wheel games here:
Reverse Engineering Legacy iPod Click Wheel Games
I do not have the required reputation to create an ipod tag just yet.  Could someone with 150+ rep edit my post and create the tag?

status-completed
Igor Skochinsky created the ipod tag for my question.
